# Have a common provider for subclasses using Guice?

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I am trying to implement a common provider for all the subclasses, imagine some schema:
`SuperComponent.class` is the parent of `ComponentA.class` and `ComponentB.class`.
I have the provider:

```
    @Provides
<T extends SuperComponent> List<T> providesComponents(Provider<T> provider) {
    List<T> componentList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        componentList.add(provider.get());
    }
    return componentList;
}
```

The idea is to call this provider when  is required the objects `List<ComponentA>` and/or `List<ComponentB>` in another class' constructor.
Imagine something like:

```
public class ResourceManager {

List<ComponentA> componentAList;
List<ComponentB> componentBList;    

@Inject
public ResourceManager(List<ComponentA> componentAList, List<ComponentB> componentBList) {
    this.componentAList = componentAList;
            this.componentBList = componentBList;
}
```

I get an error saying:

```
1) com.google.inject.Provider<T> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.
```

How can I make it work? I know I can do it creating different providers for each of the `List<ComponentA>` and `List <ComponentB>` but I need it as in the reality the number of components is much larger than 2...

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a good built-in way to handle this--Guice can bind a lot, or inspect and manipulate its bindings, but does not have good interfaces to create meta-level bindings. You do have a few options, though:

1. Leave the List-constructing to the consumer, through Providers:

   ```
   public static <T> List<T> createList(Provider<T> provider) {
     List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       list.add(provider.get());
     }
     return list;
   }

   @Inject MyConsumer(Provider<Foo> depProvider) {
     List<Foo> myFoos = createList(depProvider);
   }
   ```
2. List out the classes you need to bind like that and create the Providers in your `configure` method:

   ```
   public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
     public void configure() {
       List<Class<?>> classList = Lists.newArrayList(Class1.class, Class2.class);
       for (Class<?> clazz : classList) {
         bind(listOf(clazz)).toProvider(new ComponentListProvider<?>(getProvider(clazz)));
       }
     }

     private static <T> Key<List<T>> listOf(Class<T> clazz) {
       return new Key<List<T>>() {};
     }

     private static class ComponentListProvider<T> implements Provider<List<T>>() {
       private final Provider<T> wrappedProvider;

       ComponentListProvider(Provider<T> wrappedProvider) {
         this.wrappedProvider = wrappedProvider;
       }

       @Override public List<T> get() {
         return createList(wrappedProvider);
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   This uses [`getProvider`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/AbstractModule.html#getProvider%28java.lang.Class%3CT%3E%29), an extremely handy method that retrieves a typed `Provider` that will work as soon as the `Injector` is created (but not before).
3. Write a module that does one of the above by iterating across every binding in the Module using [Guice SPI](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/InspectingModules).

Hope that helps!